# LIs not sorting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Hi I have left side navigation which gets bind as  $("#navigation-treeview").kendoTreeView as below

```
     $("#navigation-treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ListAll", "Knowledgebase"))",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: function () {
                        var data = {};
                        var tokenInput = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
                        if (tokenInput.length) {
                            data.__RequestVerificationToken = tokenInput.val();
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "SEName",
                    hasChildren: "Children",
                    children: "Children",
                    SEName: "SEName"
                }
            }
        },
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataSpriteCssClassField: "SpriteCssClass",
        @if (TempData.ContainsKey("Nodes"))
        {
            <text>
                dataBound: expandNavigation([@Html.Raw(TempData["Nodes"])]),
            </text>
        }                    
        select: preventParentSelection,
        template: navigationTemplate()                   
    });
    sortCategyList("k-group");
});
function sortCategyList(ul, sortDescending) {

    if (typeof ul == "string")
        ul = document.getElementsByClassName(ul)[0];
    alert(ul);               
    if (!ul) {                    
        return;
    }

    var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");              
     var lis =ul.querySelectorAll("li");
    var vals = [];

    for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
        vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

    vals.sort();

    if (sortDescending)
        vals.reverse();

    for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
        lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}
```

Here what I am trying to do is when left side navigation is totally gets field by Kendo UI code then after my functions gets call and mahe that left side navigation in alphabetic format.

But the code where I placed  sortCategyList("k-group"); is giving me UL as undefined
I want my red highlighted section in alphabetic sorting order

[image]

I want it as 
    5 Formyl Tetrahydrofolate
    Burdock
    Caprylic Acid

ans the console design forms as

```
<ul class="k-group k-treeview-lines" role="group">
  <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-first" data-uid="d44db53a-44e5-4fac-a099-ca274c56d874" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true" id="navigation-treeview_tv_active" aria-selected="true">
    <div class="k-top"><span class="k-icon k-minus" role="presentation"></span><span class="k-in k-state-selected k-state-focused"><span class="k-sprite category"></span><a href="http://localhost:55390/ingredients">Ingredients</a></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="k-group" role="group" style="display: block;">
      <li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="4b2277d6-2d9d-479a-91bf-9224862ba6c6">
        <div class="k-top"><span class="k-in"><span class="k-sprite article"></span><a href="http://localhost:55390/5-formyl-tetrahydrofolate">5 Formyl Tetrahydrofolate</a></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="3666357e-f036-4026-9899-9971b8748a52">
        <div class="k-mid"><span class="k-in"><span class="k-sprite article"></span><a href="http://localhost:55390/caprylic-acid">Caprylic Acid</a></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="06064474-0b96-4d6f-9e53-2ce0a2e6986c">
        <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in"><span class="k-sprite article"></span><a href="http://localhost:55390/burdock">Burdock</a></span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li role="treeitem" class="k-item" data-uid="ad489cf4-c486-4d2d-a0fe-2de68a0ac870">
    <div class="k-mid"><span class="k-icon k-plus" role="presentation"></span><span class="k-in"><span class="k-sprite category"></span><a href="http://localhost:55390/health-conditions">Health Conditions</a></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="5b6870b8-75c0-4f0d-9c20-efd67b6fc358">
    <div class="k-bot"><span class="k-icon k-plus" role="presentation"></span><span class="k-in"><span class="k-sprite category"></span><a href="http://localhost:55390/research">Research</a></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think issue is that my function gets call  sortCategyList("k-group"); before kendoi-ui is still formatting the structure

Comment: if you log your vals array what is the result?

Comment: well it is not going to there , it gets return when UL comes as undefined

Comment: If it's not even getting to the sort, how is the sort not sorting as expected?

Comment: I need to fire my function when kendo ui functions gets completed load

Comment: You want to sort the NESTED UL so you want 
`if (typeof ul == "string")
        ul = document.getElementsByClassName(ul)[1];` instead of [0]

Comment: Also if you have `sortCategyList("k-group");`
AND `function sortCategyList(ul, sortDescending) {` AND `ul = document.getElementsByClassName(ul)[1]` it will not give you undefined unless the UL is not in the DOM when you call the script